# Reviewing Apple Store apps anonymously?

Tags: ipad, apple-store

I have tested many apps and I would like to review them in the Apple Store. I use an iPad.

I don't want to review apps under the account my credit card is tied to.

How can I review apps anonymously?

Comment: That's not how the reviews work. Maybe make a blog?

Comment: The two main reasons for anonymous reviews are: to improve the reviews of my own app, or to sabotage the reviews of my competition.  Apple has not yet figured out how to allow anonymous reviews without allowing these.

Comment: @GEdgar my main reason for anonymity is to keep me save from attacks if I leave very critical feedback to totally junk apps and privacy. I wish Apple does not reveal my email and identity if they reveal my reviews. Well I don't care less actually but some way it would be cool to have anonymous feedback.

Comment: I don't see why this question has garnered so many downvotes - it's a legitimate request, without an obvious answer. Presuming that the information is being sought for malicious purposes isn't a terribly-valid reason to downvote.

Comment: Apple does not "reveal [your] email" when they publish reviews. They do publish your Apple ID username, but I believe this can be overridden if you review using iTunes on Mac/PC instead of doing so from your phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot review anonymously but Apple offers feedback through this form [here](http://www.apple.com/feedback/itunesapp.html).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned on this [post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251535118?answerId=252998995022#252998995022):

> If you're using a Mac, open the macOS App Store and click on your name at the bottom of the sidebar on the left. If prompted, sign into your Apple ID. Then, click "View Information" from the upper right of the account page. Once the next page loads, scroll down to the "Manage" section. Here you will see your nickname and have the option to edit it. Changing the nickname here will change how the nickname appears when leaving comments/reviews on apps.
>
> If you are using a Windows computer, you can change your nickname by clicking Account > View My Account. If prompted, sign in with your Apple ID. Scroll to the "Settings" section and click the edit button next to your nickname

You can change the username if the name is what you are concerned about. aside from that, there is no option to post a review anonymously.

Answer (score 0):

I see you said your underlying reason for anonymity is

> to keep me save from attacks if I leave very critical feedback to totally junk apps and privacy

There are a few ways you could approach this.

1. Remember the person *reading* the reviews is an actual person, so treat them politely.
2. Leave the most scathing, scorched-earth, disingenuous review possible, and if they try to DOX you, oh well.
3. Don't bother leaving a review, instead go have a coffee or something else enjoyable.

Let's talk about #1, because it sounds like you want to leave a review, but not get any pushback from it. I would suggest you concentrate on the app and not the developer(s). Try to offer some kind of actionable solution with every criticism. And be nice, as if you were writing a review for your own app.

Say:

*I found the app's menu to be a bit confusing. It would make more sense to use a standard control like a hamburger—or something closer to Apple's Human Interface Design suggestions—instead of a triangle, which isn't a common element for displaying menus.*

Don't say:

*This was the absolute worst app I've ever seen! It is garbage and the person who wrote it is garbage!! They should quit development and go live on an island.*